# Admin.php in not a root folder can't be accessed

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess

I'm novice in PHP and MySQL, trying to write an elementary cms for a website. I placed all the admin part files (admin.php, update.php, insert.php, etc.) to the "admin" folder, which is in the root folder. When attempting to access www.example.com/admin/admin.php and the other files in this folder, I get an error

> No such file or directory

Must I write anything in .htaccess or somewhere else? What exactly? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you access anything in that folder?

Comment: Sounds like your web server is incorrectly configured for that directory. What web server?

Comment: Post your .htaccess, how could we know if you are doing some custom rewrites or something that is the real issue.

Comment: I haven't yet configured any .htaccess. I have no such file.

Comment: I can access an image in this folder

Comment: Forgot to say that I'm testing the project on my test subdomain
test.example.com
so the index.php file is located on the hosting by  /example.com/test/index.php
and admin.php worked correctly in this directory, but after replacing it to /example.com/test/admin/admin.php - it can't be accessed

Comment: So you can open `http://example.com/test/index.php` but cannot open `http://example.com/test/admin/admin.php`?